# Is ${p^2+1 \choose p}$ always divisible by $p$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime. Does $p$ always divide ${p^2+1 \choose p}$? We have 
$$ 
{p^2+1 \choose p} = \frac{(p^2+1)p^2(p^2-1)\cdots (p^2-p+1)}{p(p-1)\cdots 2 \cdot 1}.
$$
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Since $p$ is prime, the denominator has only one factor of $p$. How many factors of $p$ are there in the numerator?

Answer (score 0):

The highest power of $p$ dividing ${p^2+1 \choose p}$ is $\sum_{i \geqslant 1} \left ( \lfloor \frac {p ^ 2 + 1} {p ^ i} \rfloor  - \lfloor \frac {p ^ 2 - p + 1} {p ^ i} \rfloor \right ) - 1$ obviously. For $i > 2$ the term under the sum is clearly $0$, and so it is sufficient to evaluate $\sum_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant 2} \left ( \lfloor \frac {p ^ 2 + 1} {p ^ i} \rfloor  - \lfloor \frac {p ^ 2 - p + 1} {p ^ i} \rfloor \right ) - 1$ to obtain what we are looking for, and that is $2 - 1 = 1$. So, $p$ divides ${p^2+1 \choose p}$ but $p ^ 2$ does not.